# UITextField turn places with UILabel in the UITableView during scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a strange problem with UITableView and UITextField inside the cell (as subview).

In the window view (UITableView, grouped, scrollable) there are two sections.

First section has got 5 rows:

```
1.1 - cell with UITextField 
1.2 - cell with UILabel
1.3 - cell
1.4 - cell with UITextField
1.5 - cell with UISwitchButton
```

and the second section has got 1 row:

```
2.1 - cell
```

**Scenario**: I touch row `1.1` and the keyboard appear. I can enter some text.

**Problem:**  when I scroll down the UITableView to the row `2.1` without pressing `Done` on the keyboard (so the keyboard is still on the screen) and than I press `Done` something strange happen and the subview of cell `1.2` with UILabel turn places with subview of cell `1.1` with UITextField.

I have tried workaround with `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;` it helps, but I really do want to use scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused because your tableview re-uses the cells. The UITableView attempts to keep as little cells in memory as possible, so when you have 5 rows on screen your tableview will look like this:

```
cell 1 
cell 2
cell 3 
cell 4 
cell 5
```

If you then scroll down so cell1 and 2 are hidden your tableview will look like this

```
cell 3
cell 4
cell 5
cell 1
cell 2
```

The tableview can do this, because you should set the data outside of the actual cell creation and you should use a different cell identifier for cells that are different from the other.

In your case not setting the re-use identifier to nil, or using a unique re-use identifier for every different cell you are going to show should solve the problem.